# XAMPP on external 4 TB USB 3.0 drive not working as expected

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

I can't seem to start MySQL on my external USB 3.0 drive.

In the past, I haven't had problems working off of external drives. This is the first time using a large drive. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

This is from my error log.

```
130718 11:53:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130718 11:53:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130718 11:53:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130718 11:53:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130718 11:53:44 InnoDB: Unrecognized value O_DIRECT for innodb_flush_method
130718 11:53:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130718 11:53:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130718 11:53:44 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
130718 11:53:44 [ERROR] Aborting

130718 11:53:44 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

`my.ini`

```
    # Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# /xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is /xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2560M
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_thread_concurrency   = 16
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

updated error log:

```
    130718 13:06:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130718 13:06:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130718 13:06:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130718 13:06:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130718 13:06:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.5G
InnoDB: VirtualAlloc(2719744000 bytes) failed; Windows error 87
130718 13:06:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130718 13:06:24 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
130718 13:06:24 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130718 13:06:24 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130718 13:06:24 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
130718 13:06:24 [ERROR] Aborting

130718 13:06:24 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause of Problem

Right from your error log

```
130718 11:53:44 InnoDB: Unrecognized value O_DIRECT for innodb_flush_method
```

The `innodb_flush_method` option `O_DIRECT` is not supported in Windows. Why?

According to the [MySQL Documentation on `innodb_flush_method`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method)

> Controls the system calls used to flush data to the InnoDB data files and log files, which can influence I/O throughput. This variable is relevant only for Unix and Linux systems. On Windows systems, the flush method is always async_unbuffered and cannot be changed.

### Solution

Go find that option and comment it out of `my.ini` as follows:

```
[mysqld]
#innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

or just remove that line.

Then, restart mysql.

#### Give it a Try !!!

### UPDATE 2013-07-18 13:08 EDT

Look at this section of your `my.ini` you just posted

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2560M
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_thread_concurrency   = 16
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
## UTF 8 Settings
```

You still have `innodb_flush_method` configured. Please comment it out like this:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2560M
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_thread_concurrency   = 16
#innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
## UTF 8 Settings
```

and restart mysql.

#### UPDATE 2013-07-18 13:11 EDT

Look at the buffer pool size

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2560M
```

That's 2.5G or RAM for the buffer pool. You don't have enough RAM available. Lower it to 1.5G

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1536M
```

and restart mysql

Comment: thank you for the help,  i already had that un commented, please look at my updated question

Comment: You need to comment it out or remove that line. Then, restart mysql.

Comment: ok, commented it out but still an error.  updated the error log